# Case statement in join condition in oracle

Tags: oracle, join, dynamic-sql, case-when

I have below procedure in which i am using db link dynamically in sql query and i have situation where i am trying to use `case statement` in join condition because depend on the db link i have to use table in join condition but i am getting error as `ORA-06512 "missing right parenthesis"`.

```
PROCEDURE "EXT_I_IN"(IN_I_ID IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0) AS

    err_code VARCHAR(100);
    err_msg VARCHAR(100);         
     l_sql VARCHAR2(5000);
     l_sql1 VARCHAR2(5000);

    BEGIN       

    FOR I_ROW IN I_CUR
    LOOP

    l_sql:='INSERT INTO I_IN(ID,DB_LINK)
    Select DISTINCT(INC.ID),:IN_DB_LINK  FROM
    IN_I@'||IN_DB_LINK||' IC JOIN 
    (CASE WHEN :DB_NAME = ''IDB'' THEN IC.INC@'||IN_DB_LINK||' ELSE IN.INC@'||IN_DB_LINK||' END) IDL
    ';

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('lsql' || l_sql);
    execute immediate l_sql using IN_DB_LINK;

    END EXT_I_IN;'
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could copy the output of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('lsql' || l_sql);`

Comment: please check the questioni have shown the result now of dbms_output_line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks wierd, you cannot use CASE in JOIN:

```
 (CASE WHEN :DB_CONNECTION_NAME = ''FONIC_RETAIL'' THEN RATOR_FONIC_CDR.INVOICE_DETAIL_LINE@'||IN_DB_LINK||' ELSE RATOR_CDR.INVOICE_DETAIL_LINE@'||IN_DB_LINK||' END) IDL
```

But you can check this condition while building query:

```
l_sql:='INSERT INTO TEMP_TOPUP_DRC_IN(ID,INVOICE_DETAIL_LINE_ID,STATUS,BILLING_GROUP_ID,DB_LINK)
    Select DISTINCT(INC.ID),INC.INVOICE_DETAIL_LINE_ID,INC.STATUS,IDL.BILLING_GROUP_ID,:IN_DB_LINK  FROM
    IN_NODE_CHARGE@'||IN_DB_LINK||' INC JOIN ';
CASE WHEN IN_DB_LINK = 'FONIC_RETAIL' THEN l_sql := l_sql || ' RATOR_FONIC_CDR.INVOICE_DETAIL_LINE@'||IN_DB_LINK;
     ELSE l_sql := l_sql || ' RATOR_CDR.INVOICE_DETAIL_LINE@'||IN_DB_LINK;
END CASE;
l_sql := ' IDL ON INC.INVOICE_DETAIL_LINE_ID = IDL.ID
    JOIN ACCOUNT_PAYMENT@'||IN_DB_LINK||' AP ON IDL.BILLING_RECORD_ID = AP.ID
      WHERE AP.PAYMENT_TYPE_ID = 24
      AND INC.STATUS IN (1,3,6,2,4,14,20,21,100,101,102)';
```

Comment: what looks weird ? i have mentioned everything in my question. Yes if possible i want to use condition join but with db link dynamic.

Comment: i have tried you solution but getting error as encounter the symbol case when when expecting...Because i put the query in varaible its difficult to find where i have to close the single inverted comma

Comment: Semicolon was missing before 'else' and 'end case'. Check now. Also i cannot see declaration of KPI_DEF_CUR

Comment: yes because i have declare that but did not mention in my code because of the code will be lengthy. Now i am getting error as ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement. I think the alias IDL is missing which we are assinging for this case statement table.

Comment: Can you post DBMS_OUTPUT again?

Comment: i tried that but getting the same error. Please check the update dbms output line in question.

Comment: I have added another dbms after end case and it looks fine but dont know why this error is coming

Comment: Now your output is too short, first part missing. It should start with Insert into...  Make sure if sql is concatenated correcly, e.g. with dbms_output each part.   If "  l_sql := l_sql ||  " is present it should work.